# Selecting sets, multisets, and ordered pairs from the letters of the word PROPOSITION

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Can someone help me to check the answer for (a) and (d). I am not sure how to do question (b) and (c), I have tried several times, but still can't manage to solve this question. Need the answer for exam revision.

> All four parts of this question refer to the following scrabble tiles. You do not need to understand the game of scrabble to answer the question. All you need to know is that it is played with tiles. Each tile has one letter on it, and a point value in the bottom right hand corner (e.g. "P" is worth 3 points). $$P_3R_1O_1P_3O_1S_1I_1T_1I_1O_1N_1$$

> Note that there are some repeated tiles. For example the two I tiles are identical. For the first 3 parts of the question, we place all of the above tiles into a bag.

> 1. Two tiles showing different letters are taken from the bag and a 2-element set is formed containing the two letters on the tiles. How many sets can be formed in this way? (Examples of sets that can be formed in this way include $\{I,P\}$ and $\{O,R\}$.)

Answer = ?

My answer for this question is $21$

> 2. Two tiles are selected from the bag and a 2-element multiset is formed containing the letters on the tiles. How many multisets can be formed in this way? (Examples of multisets that can be formed in this way include $\{I,O\}$ and $\{O,O\}$.)

Answer = ?

Not sure how to do this question.

> 3. A tile is taken from the bag and left aside, and then another tile is taken from the bag. An ordered pair is formed whose first coordinate is the letter on the first tile and whose second coordinate is the letter on the second tile. How many possible ordered pairs can be formed in this way? (Examples of ordered pairs that can be formed in this way include $(R,I)$ and $(I,I)$.)

Answer = ?

Not sure how to do this question

> 4. Suppose that the pictured tiles get split between two bags. Which of the following statements follows from the pigeonhole principle?
>    a. One bag will contain at least 7 tiles, the other bag will have at most 4 tiles.
>    b. Both bags will have the same number of tiles in them.
>    c. Both bags must contain a tile with the letter O on it.
>    d. One bag will contain at least 7 tiles, the other bag will have at least 4 tiles.
>    e. One bag will have at least 8 points in total on its tiles, the other bag will have at least 7 points in total on its tiles.
>    f. One bag will have at least 8 points in total on its tiles, the other bag will have at most 7 points in total on its tiles.

My answer for this question is f (I am also not quite sure).

Comment: At the first problem, I got 21 = 7 choose 2. How did you obtain 66?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting a link to an image.  Links can get broken.  Images cannot be searched and may not be readable by users who use screen readers.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you see it clearly?

Comment: Your answer to the fourth question is correct.  Your answer for the first question is not.  It would be easier to detect any errors you have made if you explained how you obtained your answer.  Remember that some of the tiles are indistinguishable.

Comment: is it 21 for first question

Comment: That is correct. You should update your answer and explain how you obtained it.

Comment: ok, but I still dont know how to do question b and c

Answer (score 1):

> All four parts of this question refer to the following scrabble tiles. You do not need to understand the game of scrabble to answer the question. All you need to know is that it is played with tiles. Each tile has one letter on it, and a point value in the bottom right hand corner (e.g. "P" is worth 3 points). $$P_3R_1O_1P_3O_1S_1I_1T_1I_1O_1N_1$$

> Note that there are some repeated tiles. For example the two I tiles are identical. For the first 3 parts of the question, we place all of the above tiles into a bag.

> 1. Two tiles showing different letters are taken from the bag and a 2-element set is formed containing the two letters on the tiles. How many sets can be formed in this way? (Examples of sets that can be formed in this way include $\{I,P\}$ and $\{O,R\}$.)

There are seven distinct letters in the word PROPOSITION.  We can select two of them in
$$\binom{7}{2} = 21$$
ways, so your answer is correct.

That said, if I were your instructor, I would not give you full credit if you did not justify your answer.

> 2. Two tiles are selected from the bag and a 2-element multiset is formed containing the letters on the tiles. How many multisets can be formed in this way? (Examples of multisets that can be formed in this way include $\{I,O\}$ and $\{O,O\}$.)

There are two cases to consider.  Either the two elements of the multiset are distinct, or they are the same.  You already handled the case when they are distinct above.  In how many ways can you select two letters from the word PROPOSITION that are the same?  Keep in mind that identical letters are indistinguishable.  Since these two cases are mutually exclusive, you must add the two results.

> 3. A tile is taken from the bag and left aside, and then another tile is taken from the bag. An ordered pair is formed whose first coordinate is the letter on the first tile and whose second coordinate is the letter on the second tile. How many possible ordered pairs can be formed in this way? (Examples of ordered pairs that can be formed in this way include $(R,I)$ and $(I,I)$.)

Again, either the two letters in the ordered pair are different or they are the same.

If they are different, how many ways can the first entry be chosen?  Given that the second entry must be different from the first entry, in how many ways can the second entry be chosen?  Since the number of choices for the second entry does not depend on what you choose for the first entry, you must multiply the number of choices for the first entry by the number of choices for the second entry.

If the two entries are the same, in how many ways can the repeated letter be chosen from the letters which appear in the word PROPOSITION?

Since these two cases are mutually exclusive, you must add the results.

> 4. Suppose that the pictured tiles get split between two bags. Which of the following statements follows from the pigeonhole principle?
>    a. One bag will contain at least 7 tiles, the other bag will have at most 4 tiles.
>    b. Both bags will have the same number of tiles in them.
>    c. Both bags must contain a tile with the letter O on it.
>    d. One bag will contain at least 7 tiles, the other bag will have at least 4 tiles.
>    e. One bag will have at least 8 points in total on its tiles, the other bag will have at least 7 points in total on its tiles.
>    f. One bag will have at least 8 points in total on its tiles, the other bag will have at most 7 points in total on its tiles.

Your answer is correct.

The number of points in the Scrabble word $P_3R_1O_1P_3O_1S_1I_1T_1I_1O_1N_1$ is
$$2 \cdot 3 + 1 + 3 \cdot 1 + 1 + 2 \cdot 1 + 1 + 1 = 15$$
If neither bag had a total of at least eight points on it tiles, there could be at most $2 \cdot 7 = 14$ points on all the tiles.  If both bags had a total of at least eight points on its tiles, the number of points on all the tiles would be at least $2 \cdot 8 = 16$.  Thus, by the Pigeonhole Principle, one bag will have a total of least eight points on its tile, while the other bag can have a total of at most seven points on its tiles.

As for the other choices, we could have six tiles in one bag and five on the other, which contradicts (a), (b), and (d).  We could put all three $O$s in the same bag, which contradicts (c). We could place all the letters other than N in one bag, which would leave a total of one point in the bag containing that tile, which contradicts (e).

Comment: for question (b) is it 21+ 3C2 x 2C1 + 2C1 x 1C1 + 2C1 x 1C1 = 31 or it is 21 + 11C2

Comment: for question (c) is it 11C1 x 10C1 = 110 or is it 7C1 x 6C1 + 3 = 45

Comment: sorry for question (c) is that 2(21) + 10 = 52

Comment: For question 2, there are $\binom{7}{2}$ multisets with two different elements and three ($\{P, P\}, \{O, O\}, \{I, I\}$) with two identical elements, which gives you a total of $\binom{7}{2} + 3 = 21 + 3 = 24$.  What matters here are which elements are selected, not which tiles are selected.

Comment: Question 3:  Since there are seven distinct letters in the word PROPOSITION, the number of ordered pairs with distinct entries is $7 \cdot 6 = 42$ since there are seven choices for the first entry but only six choices for the second entry since it must be different from the first entry.  There are three ordered pairs with identical entries:  $(P, P), (O, O), (I, I)$.   That gives a total of $7 \cdot 6 + 3 = 45$ possible ordered pairs.  Again, what matters is which elements appear in the ordered pair, not which tiles are selected.

Comment: I got it, very much thanks, appreciate